# Is this the right way to use MAX Function for MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

In column_1 is just numbers from 1-10 with 10 rows. I am trying to find the biggest number and take that and eventually add it to another column.

```
private ResultSet nrs;

nrs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(column_1) FROM table");

while(nrs.next()){
     biggestNum = nrs.getInt("column_1");   
}
```

It keeps on throwing error 'Column "column_1" not found'.

Please help.

Comment: A stylistic point - since the part inside `{ }` will only  be iterated at most once, it would make sense to replace `while` with `if`.  It won't make any difference to what your code does, but it will communicate the intention of the code more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `nrs.getInt("column_1")` with `nrs.getInt(1)`

You haven't specified a name for the value you selected, so the database will choose its own.  You don't know what that name will be, so just use the column number.

Answer (score 1):

Not really familiar with java but i am with sql. column_1 does not exist cause it is already aggregated. try this:

```
private ResultSet nrs;

nrs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(column_1) as maxColumn1 FROM table");

while(nrs.next()){
     biggestNum = nrs.getInt("maxColumn1");   
}
```

But im pretty sure there is a better way to do this